# Regex to generate only numbers

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression to generate numbers for the variable 'session.ID=2211090' and
I am going to use this regex in Jmeter's post Processor-Regular Expression Extractor.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: regexp to generate numbers?  I don't think you're using the right tool...

Comment: When you say “numbers”, don’t you really mean strings of digits?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean a regular expression to extract those numbers, then this should do it: `session.ID=(\d+)`

If you're replacing, replace with just $1 or \1, depending the language. Or if you're just wanting to use the numbers, then use the first capture, however you do that in the language you're using.

Comment: This 'session.ID=(\d+)' is not working and everytime i get only one value (digit) for the variable 'session.ID as 'session.ID=1' or 'session.ID=6'  please help me in this...

Comment: It would help if you showed the code you're using. At present, I don't even know what language you're using. You could try adding $ to the end though, might fix it.

Comment: I am trying this regex expression in Jmeter's Post Processor-Regular Expression Extractor  and the code is as follows Response Field to Check-Body Reference Name-R,Regular Expression-(\d+),Template- $1$,Match No-0,Dafault Value-'-' (left blank)

Comment: Oh, I meant add the $ to the regular expression, not the Template/replace.